# jQuery - Best way to hide element? ( to prevent the element from flashing before actually hiding it )

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, element

I remember that at some point Opera `( Mostlikely it was Safari instead. )` had a problem that if you used `.hide()` on element, it would flash briefly before it would actually hide the element.

Now if you dont want to ignore those who for some reason dont have js on in their browser you cant really use CSS to set `display: none;` in that element to hide it and then use js to for example fade it in.

I recently noticed that this didnt happen anymore in Opera. So, i'd like to know if this still does happen in some browsers incase ive missed that.. And asuming that this would happen. What way would be the safest way to do it? ( of course ignoring the css method in this case. )

js `.hide()`

js `.addClass('hide')` css `.hide { display: none; }`

Or something else?

Edit:

js `element.style.display = "none"`

js `$(element).css({display:"none"})`

Edit2: This issue might have been in Safari actually. I also got thinking that newer jquery versions might have fixed the issue.. As i think there was a few bug reports about this problem on jquery website but i couldnt find those bug reports ..Or it could still be that newer browser version fixed it.. Not sure.

---

### Edit3:

So, I did indeed find a lot more about this when I started searching for this bug in Safari rather than Opera. Though i cant say for sure that it never happened in opera as well...

It would seem like this problem does not exist anymore and that it is safe to use `.hide()` but what I learned was that this `$(element).css({display:"none"})` did fix the problem when the problem was still out there.

Comment: `element.style.display = "none"` or `$(element).css({display:"none"})` are options too.

Comment: [This article](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/classchange.html) may be useful to you as well for deciding which is faster, but other than that I actually have no idea

Comment: read this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700865/best-way-to-hide-disable-gui-elements-based-on-users-privilege

Comment: Do you want to take it out of the flow when hiding it or simply make it invisible?  I prefer `visibility: hidden` during loading because the element remains within the content flow and nothing else moves around.

Comment: Doesn't really make a difference @Sparky672 I mean.. that doesnt really affect the flashing or the load time.. I believe so. Either way, if its `display: none` you can always craft it to look like `visibility: hidden` if its so important.

Comment: @Lollero:  No difference to load time but flashing, maybe.  After all, with `visibility:hidden`, the object is already within the content flow and it only needs to be revealed, however with `display:none`, all the content must slide around to make room as you hide/reveal the object... surely that contributes to the flashing effect.  And what's the advantage of going through the effort of crafting `display:none` to look like `visibility:hidden` when you could just use the one you want in the first place?

Comment: @Sparky672 The problem was that the content that was being hidden with `.hide()` did load up into the page as any clearly visible element before it was able to actually hide the element. It was only a load or refresh issue at least from my point of view. For me, this has nothing to do with how the hiding and or showing will affect the elements around it. My point about making the `display: none;` element to behave like `visibility: hidden;` element was that if.. say `.hide()` is the best way to do this, then so be it.. as you cant really control how `.hide()` hides.

Comment: @Lollero:  I'm not really making an endorsement here which is why I didn't post an answer.  Merely pointing out that there are other ways to do this, each with pros & cons.

Comment: I've found that you're more likely to get an element flashing visible before it gets hidden if it's in the domready block.  Taking it out of the domready and into the flow before the domready may well work, though I don't know if it's best practice that way or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always rely on using `jQuery` `hide()` method to hide any element because it takes care of all the browsers. I haven't seen any issues in `Opera` though.

Even to show any element you should always rely on using `show()` method again for the same reason.

E.g. To show a `tr` element if we say `tr.css("display", "block")` it will not work in Firefox because it is a table row and it needs to be specified as `.css("display", "table-row")`. But if you use `tr.show()` you dont have to worry about any browser.

Comment: Well, not entirely true, cause you can just do `.css('display','none');` to hide, and `.css('display', '');` to show.

Comment: @Alxandr that may work in this situation but setting `.css('foo','')` is not entirely safe in all browsers.  I actually submitted a ticket for Prototype a couple of years back because in IE setting `opacity` to `''` defaults to 0.  In some browsers, setting to empty is not the same as never setting it. (N.B. I stopped using prototype when said ticket was closed as being "expected behaviour" because Prototype set opacity to '', which defaulted to 0 in IE, when you passed in 1 to the function).

Answer (score 0):

You could use noscript to provide an alternative element that is always displayed, whilst the JS element starts off hidden.

Or you could use start out with a class with no CSS rules and then get a script to alter the CSS class rule to make sure the element starts off hidden.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            p.start-hidden-if-js-enabled {              
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.display = "none";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="start-hidden-if-js-enabled">
            This text will be hidden if javascript is enabled.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a display:none in a stylesheet or put an inline style="display:none" on the element.

Comment: I mentioned that in my question. Point of the question is to show the element if javascript is disabled and this doesn't quite fit in there.