# White flash before page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, optimization

Well, now its black flash, because I colored body to black. 
So it seems the flash comes from the background video that is not loaded yet.. But then why do i also see white flash when i go to the next page? There is no video there?

Website -> www.universityofempathy.com

Please let me know how i can fix this. 
I have tried hiding the body on page load and then when window is loaded, show it. But that is not fixing anything.

What iv tried:

```
$(document).load(function () {

    $('body').hide();
   $(window).load(function(){
        $('body').show();
});
```

Comment: page load and window load are the same thing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Best way to hide element? ( to prevent the element from flashing before actually hiding it )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141359/jquery-best-way-to-hide-element-to-prevent-the-element-from-flashing-before)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its most likely due to trying to hide it with JS because that in itself takes time (very short amount of time) to be performed. Instead, you should use css to handle it at the start. So you could just add:

```
body {
    display: none;
}
```

And once its ready to be shown, you run `$('body').show()`.

---

Also, you should use the [ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) listener, not `load` for `$(document)`

Comment: Its a little bit better but there is still a flash, but its just probably because they have to download the video. It won't get any better. 

Also don't understand why people downvote my question.